# Use a function loaded in a string

Tags: function, powershell

Okay this is a weird one but so image my code is,

```
$string = "Function Get-Something {Write-host 'You got something'}"
```

now i want to load that function from the string into my PS memory so i can call it... 
so 
    Invoke-Expression "$string"
will do this but i need to use the invoke line within another function.
functception..

```
function Validate-something {

$string = "Function Get-Something {Write-host 'You got something'}"
invoke-expression $string
}
Validate-Something
Get-something
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

note: I cant write the string to a file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot-source the defining function to have the inner function accessible in the calling scope subsequently:

```
. Validate-Something
Get-Something
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, worked it out...

So I needed to set the scope of the fuctions I'm calling e.g.

```
function Validate-something {
$string = "Function script:Get-Something {Write-host 'You got something'}"
invoke-expression $string
}
Validate-Something
Get-something
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future...